# for-comprehension vs Future.sequence

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

There are 4 cores on my machine.

And I thought that for-comprehension schedules stuff in paraller (not to be depended on previous result..same as flatMap):

```
val stuffResult: Future[String] = for {
   stuff1 <- service1.doServiceStuff("service 1")  // worker-5 (4+1)
   stuff2 <- service1.doServiceStuff("service 2")
   stuff3 <- service1.doServiceStuff("service 3")
   stuff4 <- service1.doServiceStuff("service 4")
 } yield (stuff1 + ", " + stuff2 + ", "+ stuff3 + ", " + stuff4)
```

where

```
 class Service {

 implicit val blockingExContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(null: Executor)

 def doServiceStuff(name:String): Future[String] = {
    Future {
      blocking {    
        println ( s"start ${name} on " + Thread.currentThread.getName)
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        "stuff_done"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what i see is (each step takes ~5 seconds):

- start service 1 on ForkJoinPool-3-worker-5
- start service 2 on ForkJoinPool-3-worker-5
- start service 3 on ForkJoinPool-3-worker-5
- ERROR:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]

all runs on one thread, instead of use existing FREE one and finish all as fast as possible - in ~5 secs.

But if I go with:

```
val stuff1 = service1.doServiceStuff("service 1")
val stuff2 = service1.doServiceStuff("service 2")
val stuff3 = service1.doServiceStuff("service 3")
val stuff4 = service1.doServiceStuff("service 4")

Future.sequence(List(stuff1, stuff2, stuff3, stuff4)).map { list =>
  list.foldLeft("") { (acc, x) => acc + " " + x }
}
..
```

all ends in 5 second.

At which pont for-comprehension works sequentially? Does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work sequentially, it just cannot start the `Future`s till they are created (which would happen in your case in your `flatMap` of your previous `Future`), so you need to create them in advance if you want to process them in parallel (with the usual implicit `ExecutionContext`s).

Probably [this tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#functional-composition-and-for-comprehensions) explains better though (it complicates it with `withFilter`):

> The purchase future is completed only once both usdQuote and chfQuote
>   are completed– it depends on the values of both these futures so its
>   own computation cannot begin earlier.
>
> The for-comprehension above is translated into:
>
> `val purchase = usdQuote flatMap {   usd =>   chfQuote`
>   `.withFilter(chf => isProfitable(usd, chf))`
>   `.map(chf => connection.buy(amount, chf)) }`
>
> which is a bit harder to grasp than the for-comprehension, but we analyze it to better
>   understand the flatMap operation. The flatMap operation maps its own
>   value into some other future. Once this different future is completed,
>   the resulting future is completed with its value. In our example,
>   flatMap uses the value of the usdQuote future to map the value of the
>   chfQuote into a third future which sends a request to buy a certain
>   amount of Swiss francs. The resulting future purchase is completed
>   only once this third future returned from map completes.

What you would really only need is something like [`map2`](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/parallelism/Par.scala#L19) instead of `flatMap`, as you do not use the returned value from the previous `Future` to create the new `Future`.

Comment: doServiceStuff creates a future if it was invoked. (?)

Comment: @ses Exactly. The difference between the two, that in the first case it is not invoked till the previous `Future`'s result is ready (as you _might_ use that value in the `flatMap` to create a new `Future` using `doServiceStuff`).

Comment: (Unfortunately Scala do not have a nice syntax like for comprehensions to a method like `map2`.)

Comment: I put a note about this: https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/MapFlatMapFor.scala